# Binary data type C++

Tags: c++, types

I would like to have a data type that stores a binary number that is 21 digits long that I can do operations on.  I tried

```
unsigned long long int
```

and it was just barely to small.  This is wasting a lot of space bc my number is binary an the computer is storing it a a integer so the question is is there a type that stores it as a binary number but I can still do like modular operations on it.

I read a few related posts and did not think they quite addressed my question.  If there is one I missed I would appreciate some one pointing me there thanks.

Update so hear is a snipit of the code that is the problem

It is crashing after

```
unsigned long long int a;
cin>>a;
```

Which in tern must go to

```
void convertNumtoArray(unsigned long long int  a, x & binaryA){ 
        int j=0;                               
        while(a!=0){                          
                unsigned long long int remainder=a % 10;
                a=a/10;
                binaryA.a[j]=remainder;
                binaryA.length_a=j+1;
                j++;
        }
}
```

Comment: 21 binary digits is 21 bits.  If that isn't what you mean by "stores a binary number that is 21 digits long" you should clarify.

Comment: yes but using unsigned long long int the computer thinks its a int and I want it to know it is binary

Comment: or am I thinking about it wrong

Comment: Why wouldn't you use boolean array of the length 21?

Comment: How do you tell that `int` (or `unsigned long long`) isn't represented as *binary*?

Comment: try http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Comment: Oh yes it does store it as binary doesn't it

Comment: how many bits does unsigned long long use bc it is crashing at 21 but working fine for small numbers

Comment: 21 bits have 2^21 = 2097152 possible states

Comment: Perhaps you could show us an example of the code that crashes. An unsigned long long is generally 64 bits which is much more than you need, but I'm going to guess the way you're working with it is the problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I posted it

Comment: `unsigned long` is at least 32 bits, so it should also be more than wide enough. `uint_least32_t` should be the narrowest integer type that can hold 21 bits (unless you're on a really exotic system).

Comment: ok there must be some other problem when the numbers are to big sorry for all the troble

Comment: you should explain what `x & binaryA` mean. How is type 'x' declared? And what exactly the 21 means in your case. I have an impression that you are talking about 21 decimal digits. This would be too many for a long long int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to have a data type that stores a binary number that is 21 digits long that I can do operations on.

One way to tackle this is by using `bitset`, here is an example of constructing and using of such object:

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <string>          
#include <bitset>          

int main ()
{
    std::bitset<16> foo;
    std::bitset<16> bar (0xfa2);
    std::bitset<16> baz (std::string("0101111001"));

    std::cout << "foo: " << foo << '\n';
    std::cout << "bar: " << bar << '\n';
    std::cout << "baz: " << baz << '\n';
}
```

The above prints:

```
foo: 0000000000000000
bar: 0000111110100010
baz: 0000000101111001
```

This gives you direct access over the size of the variable you want to define (in your case 21 bits?), in bits, as well as possibility for binary operations.

Comment: I cant use % though can I?

Comment: Do you mean modulo operation? You could just check the last digit, if `1` the value is odd, if `0` - the value is even

Comment: you are right however I am still curious why it is not taking my number

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long long int remainder=a % 10;
a=a/10;
```

You're dividing by ten, which means you're treating the value as a **decimal** number.  (The constant `10` is decimal, not binary.) 21 decimal digits are equivalent to approximately 70 bits, which is why `unsigned long long int` (typically 64 bits) is not wide enough.

Change `10` to `2`.  (I haven't checked for other problems in your code, but that's a start.)

(You might also consider using bitwise operators, but division by `2` should work and might be easier to understand for now.)